# Why primal LP is often defined with equation $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Suppose we have
$$\begin{cases}
-x_1 \le -1\\
\phantom{-}x_1 \le \phantom{-}2\\
-x_2 \le -1\\
\phantom{-}x_2 \le \phantom{-}2
\end{cases},$$
so 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, b = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Of course $Ax = b$ isn't solvable though region defined by $Ax \le b$ is nice and has feasible solutions. My question is:

*What kind of region can we represent with $Ax = b$ (i think it's always a subspace) and what is the rationale behind such a representation?*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but look up:

http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/m171.dir/sec_8-1.pdf

If you are currently taking an introduction course to Linear Programming, you will learn that by converting inequality to equality constraints (i.e. conversion to standard form by means of slack variables for e.g.), and then by several available methods such as the "reputable" simplex method (see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplexMethod.html & http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap7.pdf & http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18310S15/lpnotes310.pdf), will you be able to solve such optimization problems efficiently.

Several other areas of optimization such as integer programming/discrete optimization involve real-life problems such as transportation and network problems, which require integer variable and equality constraints.